# How do I return errors from my asp.net mvc controller when doing a jquery ajax post?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm creating a website in ASP.NET MVC and have stumbled across something I really can't figure out.

I've got a user profile page that allows a user to change his password. On the serverside, I want to validate that the user has entered a correct "current" password before allowing the change.

What's the best way to return to my View when the password isn't correct? I've tried using  ModelState.AddModelError and then return Json(View()) but I can't see the error message anywhere in the JSON object returned to the browser.

What's the best way to do this using jquery on the client?

/Jesper

Answer (score 2):

I would create to classes

```
JsonOK : JsonResult { ... }
JsonError : JsonResult { ... }
```

And use those 2 for OK and Error responses.

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return JsonError(ex.Message);
    // or output your own message
    // or pass into it ModelState with your errors
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ModelState does not automatically do anything with the returned `Json`. You should manually fill in a model object with data you want to return to the client.

Alternatively, if you want to report *errors* to the client, you can throw an exception in the controller action method and handle it in jQuery.